# Search engine keyword relevance

Tags: search-engine

I am looking for a dataset of search engine queries with qualitative assessments of the search results' relevancy.

I have such data from [Kaggle](http://kaggle.com) in the case of [The Home Depot](http://homedepot.com) website search queries, however I'm searching for comparable data from another source, so that I can understand the difference between portal-specific effects and portal-robust effects.

For instance, the data I have lists:

- Relevance on a scale of 1 to 3, rated by a panel with given instructions
- The search query
- The top search result's title
- The top search result's description
- Miscellaneous session and search result contextual data